# How to assign substrings of line read in loop to separate variables?

Tags: vbscript

There is a text file which has data like this :

```
1000 abc@gmail.com  
1005 xyz@ymail.com  
1003 pqr@gmail.com
```

I want to pick the number and email address from first line, save them in separate variables, perform some action, and then pick the number and email from second line, perform some action and it goes on like that.

Please let me know how to do it in VBScript.

Following is my code for opening and reading the text file:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\test.txt", 1)
Do While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream = True
    strContents = objFile.ReadLine
    WScript.Echo strContents
Loop
objFile.Close
```

Comment: You can store the values in a dynamic array

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5.aspx) a string?

```
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    arr  = Split(objFile.ReadLine, " ", 2)
    num  = arr(0)
    mail = arr(1)
    '...
Loop
```